Recommendation for OLED screen roughly the size of an American Nickel or smaller
As the title says, I'm looking to source a few OLED screens roughly that size (21.21 millimeters / 0.835 inches) or smaller. My other challenge is the driver IC's on the side of the panel - I need an OLED where those aren't visible on the side / are hidden underneath. The use case is a small,svelte piece of jewelry. I'm not seeing any on Digikey so I'm assuming they aren't out there, but figured I'd give it a shot here.

I know this isn't even remotely the same as an OLED, but you might appreciate this LED matrix earring video anyways

GL104AMC10B - 31.15mm OD/26.35mm ID 340x340 color AMOLED


Full color
Driver circuity is entirely mounted on the back, and is only 1.96mm thick
Flexible 24 pin cable to connect the display to your circuitry
Unknown pricing
Slightly bigger than desired

GDOR0075W - 23.15 OD/19.18mm ID 128x128 monochrome PMOLED (passive matrix) - $15.89


Monochrome
Driver circuitry is partially mounted to the side (below) of the display
SPI connection
About the right size

